# How to set returnUrl value in Yii

Tags: php, yii, returnurl

I am using Yii and the problem I am getting is with the `Yii::app()->user->returnUrl`. It always returns me to the `index.php` page.

How can I set its value to the page which requested the current page as I do not know from which page user has visited  the current page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer` to see where the user came from.

```
public function beforeAction()
{
    Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer;
    return parent::beforeAction();
}
```

Be careful, if the user came from a 3rd party site, then this will redirect them away from your site.

Comment: Thanks friend...and thanks for warning me about this too :) cheers

Comment: There is a typo here: Yii::app()->**user**->urlReferrer should be Yii::app()->**request**->urlReferrer.

Answer (score 6):

For those using Yii2

```
Yii::$app->user->returnUrl = Yii::$app->request->referrer;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as: `Yii::app()->user->urlReferrer`

It should be: `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer` or `Yii::app()->request->requestUri (current page)`

So try this:

```
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->user->urlReferrer;
```

Or this one (which I personally prefer):

```
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->requestUri;
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a Yii extension to manage return URLs, you can find it here:
https://github.com/cornernote/yii-return-url#yii-returnurl

It's an improvement over the way Yii handles it because it stores the return url in the GET/POST data instead of the SESSION.  This means that if you have multiple tabs open then each can have it's own return url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$http = new CHttpRequest();
$referrer_url = $http->getUrlReferrer();
$this->redirect($referrer_url);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Am I missing something, or you're wrong? If you read `getUrlReferrer` from _fresh, newly created_ `CHttpRequest` it will be... empty? You should most definitely use the one provided by application object (`Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer`), not create new one. But... maybe I'm not getting the whole picture and I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like that

```
Yii::app()->user->returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer;
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still struggling with returning to previous page: You have to create a property in login model `$referer`, and at the time when you initialize your `Login` model you set this property to `Yii::$app->request->referrer`. You have to go this way because after you submit your form your referrer does change to current page, and since it is `null`, it return you to index action. So the way how to pass the return URL is to store it in the hidden field at the form, so when you submit the form you have this URL loaded and you can perform action to return `$this->goBack($form->referer ? $form->referer : null)`.
Here is the code:

Login model:

```
public $referer;
```

Controller action:

```
$model = new Login();
$model->referer = Yii::$app->request->referrer;
...
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()){
    ...
    if($model->save()){
        return $this->goBack((($model->referer) ? $model->referer : null));
    }
}
```

View login.php:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'referer')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```