# What sets returnUrl value in Yii 1.x application (or framework internals)

Tags: php, yii, authentication, logout, redirect

What is responsible for *setting* [`returnUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser/#returnUrl-detail) property in Yii 1.x (documentation says nothing about this) and what value this property should have, if I redirect user back to login screen (`user/login` route) in `actionLogout`?

I'm facing a strange situation in my Yii application. As I wrote, my logout action redirects user back to login page. Everything seems fine, when standard user uses only frontend of my application. It logs in and logs out and all the time navigates between home page and login screen, which is fine.

However, when admin-like user logs in, goes to control panel, clicks `logout` link there and then logs in again, it is redirected to home page. This is, because `returnUrl` is set to entry script URL, not to `admin.html` (route to `Admin` module, which user has just left). Good question, why?

I've searched entire code of my application and I can clearly see, that I don't set `returnUrl` myself anywhere.

I think, that solution to my problem could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20299637/1469208). If this is true, then question is a bit different: Why this is not set by Yii internals, only have to be done by user (in `beforeAction`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `returnUrl` property uses state, that is stored in the cookie. It will be cleared after logout. In some situations you can override `CWebUser` class, by your own and override `returnURL`.

Yii has many things, which have no documentation. Feel free to browse source code, if you find someting like that. It improves your skills.

Comment: So, if I get you right, I can be sure of `returnUrl` only after login. But, after logout, I have to take care myself of either setting correct value to `returnUrl` or to not rely on it and get redirection URL other ways. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. The returnUrl stores BOTH for logged user and for guest. And yes, after logout returnUrl will be reset to default value.